# SQL "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" error on count subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

so I'm trying to join this subquery of a single column of counts:

```
​(SELECT count(u.id) FROM companies_company cc FULL JOIN auth_user u on u.company_id = cc.id FULL JOIN auth_user_groups ug ON ug.user_id= u.id FULL JOIN auth_group g ON g.id = ug.group_id  WHERE cc.deactivated is null and (email is null) GROUP BY cc.id ORDER BY cc.id)
```

To this query below.

```
SELECT cc.id , cc.name, 
    (SELECT count(*) from auth_user u where cc.id = u.company_id and (u.email is null)) as number_of_real_users,   
    (SELECT count(u.id) FROM companies_company cc FULL JOIN auth_user u on u.company_id = cc.id FULL JOIN auth_user_groups ug ON ug.user_id= u.id FULL JOIN auth_group g ON g.id = ug.group_id  WHERE cc.deactivated is null and (email is null) GROUP BY cc.id ORDER BY cc.id) as number_of_full_users,
    ss.user_permissions_enabled, cc.company_type,
    FROM companies_company cc
    FULL JOIN subscriptions_subscription ss on ss.company_id = cc.id
    WHERE cc.deactivated is null
    GROUP BY cc.id, cc.name, ss.user_permissions_enabled
    ORDER BY cc.id
```

But I am getting the error "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"...
This is unexpected as

```
(SELECT count(*) from auth_user u where cc.id = u.company_id and (u.email is null)) as number_of_real_users,
```

is another subquery I've included but that works perfect, so why can't this subquery below be added?

```
(SELECT count(u.id) FROM companies_company cc FULL JOIN auth_user u on u.company_id = cc.id FULL JOIN auth_user_groups ug ON ug.user_id= u.id FULL JOIN auth_group g ON g.id = ug.group_id  WHERE cc.deactivated is null and (email is null) GROUP BY cc.id ORDER BY cc.id) as number_of_full_users,
```

Comment: The subquery is not related to the outer query, so it'll return multiple rows per row of the outer query. You should give `companies_company` a different alias in the subquery (otherwise, what is `cc`, the inner or outer table?), and add something like `WHERE cc2.id = cc.id`.  And why all the `FULL JOINS`?

Comment: If someone answers you in a comment then ask them to post it as an answer or post it as an answer. But I get that you were commenting that a comment not answer was helpful. One can click on a comment's up arrow to agree. But comments are not permanent. Especially "thanks" comments. I mentioned click/accept of an answer just to be sure you knew about it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use group by in third query line and this query calculate the count of each `cc.id` and it is maybe returning more than one row

```sql
SELECT count(u.id) 
FROM 
  companies_company cc 
  FULL JOIN auth_user u on u.company_id = cc.id 
  FULL JOIN auth_user_groups ug ON ug.user_id= u.id 
  FULL JOIN auth_group g ON g.id = ug.group_id  
WHERE cc.deactivated is null and (email is null) 
GROUP BY cc.id 
ORDER BY cc.id
```

If no need group by and just need count remove **group by** and **order by**

**Correct query**:

```sql
SELECT count(u.id) 
FROM 
  companies_company cc 
  FULL JOIN auth_user u on u.company_id = cc.id 
  FULL JOIN auth_user_groups ug ON ug.user_id= u.id 
  FULL JOIN auth_group g ON g.id = ug.group_id  
WHERE cc.deactivated is null and (email is null)
```